# Is it possible to send webhook through NGINX proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, webhooks

I have a setup where i can access to my docker containers through nginx proxy. All containers are in internal network and does not have access to the internet.
Now I need to send webhook to slack from my docker container. In container i edited file "/etc/hosts", just added a record to my proxy, which is similiar to hooks.slack.com. I did this, because container sending request to proxy, after that proxy get it and redirects to the internet original hooks.slack.com.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hooks.slack.com;
    return 301 https://hooks.slack.com$reques_uri;
}
```

When i am testing this by CURL from my docker container i get answer 301 and nothing happened, no message delivered to slack.

**SOLVED**:

Needed to add this intead of my actual setup.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name hooks.slack.com
location / {
    proxy_pass  https://hooks.slack.com;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `proxy_pass` instead of 301 redirect

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hooks.slack.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://hooks.slack.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked out. In addition to provide authoriztion (with this i get 401 answer).